# UICollectionView Crashes on Scroll (lldb)

Tags: ios, ipad, scroll, crash, uicollectionview

I'm trying to add a uicollectionview as a subview into a View, called CollectionSpace, by calling it from Storyboard.

```
UIViewController *CollectionVC =[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CollectionVC"];
CollectionVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(CollectionSpace.frame.origin.x-276, CollectionSpace.frame.origin.y-87, CollectionSpace.frame.size.width+2, CollectionSpace.frame.size.height-2);

[CollectionSpace addSubview:CollectionVC.view];
```

The storyboard has a Collection View where the delegate and Source, as the uicollectionview have been linked to the owner view controller. Here is the code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionView; //linked

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    _collectionView=[[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame collectionViewLayout:layout];
    [_collectionView setDataSource:self];
    [_collectionView setDelegate:self];

    [_collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];
    [_collectionView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    [self.view addSubview:_collectionView];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 100;
}

// The cell that is returned must be retrieved from a call to -dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
    return cell;
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return CGSizeMake(150, 150);
}
```

So this works fine, it loads the uicollectionview and I can see the cells. The problem comes when I scroll. Once I scroll, the app crashes. (lldb)

I tried to call differently by importing the view controller and initiate it like this:

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *aFlowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
        [aFlowLayout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(200, 140)];
        [aFlowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];

        ViewController *CollectionVC = [[ViewController alloc]initWithCollectionViewLayout:aFlowLayout];
```

But the uicollectionview doesn't show up. 
Any idea what could be causing the crash?

Comment: What the crash log says?

Comment: (lldb) argc = (init) 1 ,argv = (char **) 0x27db6d04, *argv char * "/var/mobile/Applications/A2E9BB21-1248-43E7-9ee6-83E17FF27CD1/Myapp.app/Myapp" 0x27db6da8, **argv char '/' '/'

Comment: Not this. Do you find nothing else in the debugger after the crash

Comment: No nothing else, just (lldb)

Comment: Continue the execution(if this is an exception) you may get the log

Comment: Well, it points me here: @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    } EXC_BAD_ACESS(code=1, address=0x400000000c)

Comment: Now check the debugger area any log?

Comment: Then it is difficult is say why it is crashing. Put an exception breakpoint and check wether exactly its crashing

Comment: I have the same problem.Just have a little info to print `Printing description of *(argv):
(char *) *argv = 0xbfffefbc "/Users/apple/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/DA2053D3-E865-45E1-8978-74CCA41E8717/CheckPhoneNumber.app/CheckPhoneNumber"`

Comment: Did you manage to find the answer? I have same problem and I don't know what's the reason.